# Django ModelForm validation and error messages

Tags: django, validation, modelform

Sorry if this is a basic question: I am having trouble doing form validation with ModelForms in Django.

The pattern I'm using is

```
def View(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = AddPageForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid:
            instance = form.save()  
            ...

        else:
            HttpResponse("Error")
```

This works fine if the form validates (the `if`... branch is followed.) When the form doesn't validate, I get a standard Django form validation error page; the `else`... branch is ignored.

Obviously, there must be something wrong/missing but I can't work out what from the official Django documentation. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: missing **()** in `if form.is_valid` => `if form.is_valid()`, it's just a typo here?

Comment: @manji I get a ValueError: "ValueError at /add/account/
The Account could not be created because the data didn't validate."

Comment: Wow, thanks I missed it completely.

Comment: Also note that you shouldn't catch the `else` here - let it fall through to the bottom of the function, so that the form is re-rendered showing the validation errors.

Comment: @Daniel - not sure what you mean by "let it fall thought to the bottom of the function" - could you explain? Thanks

Comment: See the example [in the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

missing **()** in `if form.is_valid` => `if form.is_valid()`